# Error connecting database: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have the following error connecting to database using java:

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    com.skf.support.setup.data.database.DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:32)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:25)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:54)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.login.LoginFormValidator.validate(LoginFormValidator.java:28)
    org.apache.jsp.modules.login.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.database.DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:23)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:25)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:54)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.login.LoginFormValidator.validate(LoginFormValidator.java:28)
    org.apache.jsp.modules.login.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.database.DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:23)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:25)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.user.UserDao.checkUser(UserDao.java:54)
    com.skf.support.setup.data.login.LoginFormValidator.validate(LoginFormValidator.java:28)
    org.apache.jsp.modules.login.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

I am using phpmyadmin and my database name is: `sfsupportconnectionpool`

Here is my **web.xml**

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>Resource reference to a factory for java.sql.Connection instances 
        that may be used for talking to a particular database 
        that is configured in the Context
        configuration for the web application.</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/SFSupportConnectionPool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/SFSupportConnectionPool">
    <Resource 
        name="jdbc/SFSupportConnectionPool" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        username="dbadmin" password="12345"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sf_support?autoReconnect=true" 
        connectionProperties="removeAbandoned=true; removeAbandonedTimeout=60;"/>
</Context>
```

class for connecting to db: **DBConnection.java**

```
package com.skf.support.setup.data.database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DBConnectionFactory{
    private static String dbName = "SFSupportConnectionPool";

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        Context initContext;
        try{
            initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/" + DBConnectionFactory.dbName);
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a number of things but its not working out for me. Could anyone suggest me what could be going wrong here? I didn't create the project myself i am just trying to connect the database to the jsp application. Any help would be appreciated.! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tested this tutorial and it works perfectly http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html;

U have to read and understand it ,don't worry it's easy and it took me only 10 minutes to do it.

This is my test project,i am pretty sure that it will work.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx5i3zip5ohmls9/testt.zip

Comment: maybe i'm making a mistake in importing it using Eclipse because my setup confuses me a lot. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the mysql jar file inside lib directory of the tomcat server.

(eg: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.3\lib)

Comment: i somehow worked it out. It was tomcat's issue and it was really all a delete and install again thing. I did all those things well.